# Taiwan's post-pandemic "7-day SEP" policy

Tags: covid-19, regulations, taiwan, quarantine

Since October 2022 when Taiwan opened back up for travel they've had a ["7-day SEP" rule](https://www.cdc.gov.tw/En/Bulletin/Detail/nEBLnOPooDYFy_CBJqfWvg?typeid=158).

I learned about this on [Australia's "Smartraveller" site](https://www.smartraveller.gov.au/destinations/asia/taiwan) which usually has very up-to-date info:

> All arrivals must undertake 7 days of Self-initiated Epidemic Prevention (SEP). The SEP period can be done in a private residence, provided it meets the criteria.

I believe this replaced real quarantine with a requirement that your first seven days there are to be in a private room, not a dormitory or a room with a shared bathroom outside the room. (Let me know if my understanding is inaccurate.)

But it's now almost six months old at this point. Do we know if this rule is still enforced? Is your accommodation booking checked by immigration staff at the airport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is your accommodation booking checked by immigration staff at the airport?

The answer to this is almost certainly No, as [Timatic](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm) no longer lists any special COVID rules for Taiwan, so this rule is very unlikely to be enforced by immigration. [Hostel websites](https://www.starhostel.com.tw/faq) also don't seem to mention any restrictions. So I suspect that the rule is no longer enforced (if it even exists).

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I found out about it through Australia's Smartraveller, which is usually very up-to-date. I'll add that info to the question.

Answer (score 3):

My anecdotal answer is that on April 1 2023 they didn't even ask me about my accommodation. I might've had to write the name of it on the immigration form.

They definitely didn't ask if I'd booked one week or a single room. I had only booked one night in a hostel dormitory.

Answer (score 0):

Always check at destination country.
In this case,
https://www.immigration.gov.tw/

The language change tab is at the top left corner.